# Callbacks that mutate local state

Tags: rust, websocket, callback, lifetime, borrow-checker

I have two structs:

- Client, which stores a callback and calls it in response to receiving new data. As an example, you can think of this as a websocket client, and we want to provide a hook for incoming messages.
- BusinessLogic, which wants to hold a Client initialized with a callback that will update its local `value` in response to changes that the Client sees.

After following compiler hints, I arrived at the following minimal example:

[Rust playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f4b74bd85b476840ac39705031210507)

```rust
use rand::Rng;

struct Client<'cb> {
    callback: Box<dyn FnMut(i64) + 'cb>,
}

impl<'cb> Client<'cb> {
    fn do_thing(&mut self) {
        // does stuff

        let value = self._get_new_value();

        // does more stuff

        (self.callback)(value);

        // does even more stuff
    }

    fn _get_new_value(&self) -> i64 {
        let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
        rng.gen()
    }
}

struct BusinessLogic<'cb> {
    value: Option<i64>,
    client: Option<Client<'cb>>,
}

impl<'cb> BusinessLogic<'cb> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            value: None,
            client: None,
            
        }
    }

    fn subscribe(&'cb mut self) {
        self.client = Some(Client {
            callback: Box::new(|value| {
                self.value = Some(value);
            })
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut bl = BusinessLogic::new();
    bl.subscribe();

    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

Problem is, I am still getting the following compiler error:

```
  Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0597]: `bl` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:51:5
   |
51 |     bl.subscribe();
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
54 | }
   | -
   | |
   | `bl` dropped here while still borrowed
   | borrow might be used here, when `bl` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `BusinessLogic<'_>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

I understand why I'm seeing this error: the call to `subscribe` uses a borrow of `bl` with a lifetime of `'cb`, which is not necessarily contained within the scope of `main()`. However, I don't see how to resolve this issue. Won't I always need to provide a lifetime for the callback stored in `Client`, which will end up bleeding through my code in the form of `'cb` lifetime annotations?

More generally, I'm interested in understanding what is the canonical way of solving this callback/hook problem in Rust. I'm open to designs different from the one I have proposed, and if there are relevant performance concerns for various options, that would be useful to know also.

Answer (score 1):

What you've created is a self-referential structure, which is problematic and not really expressible with references and lifetime annotations. See: [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/2189130) for the potential problems and workarounds. Its an issue here because you want to be able to mutate the `BusinessLogic` in the callback, but since it holds the `Client`, you can mutate the callback while its running, which is no good.

I would instead suggest that the callback has full ownership of the `BusinessLogic` which does not directly reference the `Client`:

```
use rand::Rng;

struct Client {
    callback: Box<dyn FnMut(i64)>,
}

impl Client {
    fn do_thing(&mut self) {
        let value = rand::thread_rng().gen();
        (self.callback)(value);
    }
}

struct BusinessLogic {
    value: Option<i64>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut bl = BusinessLogic {
        value: None
    };
    
    let mut client = Client {
        callback: Box::new(move |value| {
            bl.value = Some(value);
        })
    };
    
    client.do_thing();

    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

- if you need the subscriber to have backwards communication to the `Client`, you can pass an additional parameter that the callback can mutate, or simply do it via return value
- if you need more complicated communication from the `Client` to the callback, either send a `Message` enum as the argument, or make the callback a custom trait instead of just `FnMut` with additional methods
- if you need a single `BusinessLogic` to operate from multiple `Client`s use `Arc`+`Mutex` to allow shared ownership

Comment: Thanks! Is there a canonical way to implement something like a websocket client in rust? Or in general, some struct that takes arbitrary callbacks and executes them in response to some events